# Greek alphabet being converted to unicode in dataframe? any packages to support use of different alphabets?

Tags: r, nlp

I created a column containing Greek words, e.g:

`vocab<-c("να", "το","δεν", "είναι")`
however, when shown in a data frame these words are shown as:

"㯚, tο, deν, eί㯚ι " respectivley.

Are there any packages that help R cope with the use of foreign alphabets and treat them the same as they would the standard English one? I don't really understand why they don't automatically treat these symbols as normal English letters.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This will probably depend on your platform (encoding).

Comment: You need to state the results of encoding on the character vector and the results of Sys.getlocale()

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "en_US.UTF-8")

vocab<-c("να", "το","δεν", "είναι")
Encoding(vocab) = "UTF-8"
cat(vocab, "\n")
να το δεν είναι
```

Comment: for me it says `OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8" cannot be honored`

Comment: I also got that message,  but it successfully displayed the Greek characters anyway.